# Are there headless wights?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Game of Thrones, S01E01, we see a White Walker cut off a mans head,

But, throughout the whole series I cannot recall a single wight with no head being shown. You see some getting their head cut off in battles, but none of them was walking in the big army with no head.

Did anyone see a headless wight anywhere in the series?

Comment: **any where in the series** would make this too broad isn't it?

Comment: @Vishwa not really. Too broad is stuff like "how are zombies depicted in film".

Comment: @Vishwa, I think I could count on two hands how episodes had wights in them.

Comment: Are wights == white walkers?  I've only seen the show, so maybe the books are clearer on this point.  I thought wights were "lieutenant" types (like the one Sam killed.)  Meaning all wights might be white walkers, but not all white walkers are necessarily wights.  Am I out to lunch on this?

Comment: @Steve-O Far less likely "lieutenants" & more like "minions". They've some significant diff tht prevent these 2 to be considered equivalent. For starters, Wight walkers (WWs) were created by the Children of the Forest 1000s of years ago for protection against the First Men while wights are simply the products of WWs (who've the ability to resurrect the dead and turn them into wights). 2ndly, wights were extremely vulnerable to fire whereas WWs are shown to be resistant to fire. Here's an interesting read- https://www.insider.com/game-of-thrones-white-walkers-wights-skeletons-difference-2017-8

Comment: i think wights can die of beheading although i don't have any reference now.

Comment: @ashveli wights have never been shown to die through beheading in the show at least.

Comment: I guess the real question is can someone beheaded *become* a wight/walker in the first place?

Comment: @Paulie_D, is that not what I asked?

Comment: @KyloRen Not really...but it's clearer now.

Answer (score 3):

So, I was reading today and saw a passage which made me immediately want to come online and post an answer to this (which I saw when first posted).

When the black brothers go to the other side of the wall to see 3 of their rangers heads on pikes:

> “I hope the Weeper burned the bodies,” said the dour man, the one called Dolorous Edd.“Elsewise they might come looking for their heads.”
>    - A dance with Dragons

I would say that this heavily implies that  we can have headless wights (at least in the mind of GRRM). Whether Doloroua Edd is correct or not is still not clear, but I think it's as close as we'll get!

Comment: It's just dark humour, typical from Edd. It doesn't mean he actually knows that headless wights exist.

Comment: @Silver as I mentioned in my answer, it implied the author has considered them and is probably as close as we can get to an answer without someone asking him outright

Comment: The question was whether it has been shown on screen or not, not if it exists in GRRM lore. You are referring to the book and OP is asking about the TV series.

Comment: @Silver the TV series is based on the book and is also over. Since its been 3 weeks since it has been asked and no one can recall a headless Wight in the TV show, as I said there is a heavy implication in the book that they do exist

Comment: @Bee: That's not an implication they do exist. It's an implication that there isn't a known reason for them _not_ to exist (because if it existed it would invalidate Edd's point and thus he wouldn't make it). That's not the same thing.

Comment: @Flater, but that's exactly my point... It implies that they could exist, or at least that G Martin believes they can. There is also an example in the book where an arm crawls along the snow, dragging its self. I think, this too, implies that they don't need a head and will add it to my answer when I have more time

Answer (score 1):

In Season 7 Episode 7, in the demonstration of wight to Cersei, they split the wight in three parts, all of them moving. So, there you have a headless wight.

[image]

Not sure if they are marching in the army, but as you can see, it is possible, until they are destroyed with fire, dragon glass or valyrian steel.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the books. But on the show I never saw a headless wight, or a living head of a wight after being detached. Cut in half sure-but it seems the "brain" or whatever the hell they have has to be attached for the "nerve" pulses to the body to work.

Comment: There are plenty of skeletal wights with no soft tissue left to contradict this theory.